# PHР Палиндром для чисел

Tags: php, массивы

Немогу понять палиндром для чисел как написать задачу :"Определить, является ли заданное натуральное число палиндромом"
нахожу толька для букв но понять не могу пожалуйста объясните как написать задачу.

Comment: Было бы круто если бы вы написали, какой ваш план для определения палиндрома для строки

Answer (score 0, accepted):

во-первых, раз вы знаете как делать для букв, число можно перевести в строку и дальше по известному алгоритму

во-вторых, можно сначала перевернуть число и потом сравнить изначальное число с перевернутом - если совпадает - это палиндром

перевернуть число можно следующим образом

```
$new_num = 0;
$pos = 0;

while ($num != 0) {
    // определить последнюю цифру числа
    $digit = $num % 10;

    // уменьшить число на 1 цифру
    $num = intdiv($num, 10);

    // увеличить новое число на 1 цифру
    $new_num = $new_num * 10 + $digit 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$q = 12345;
$r = strrev($q);

var_dump($q,$r, $q == $r);

$q = 12321;
$r = strrev($q);

var_dump($q,$r, $q == $r);
```

int 12345

string '54321' (length=5)

boolean false

int 12321

string '12321' (length=5)

boolean true